# DENY EXECUTE on one schema object hides other objects in same schema

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, permissions

I have five stored procedures in a schema [XTR], the users are all in one AD group [AD\Users] and have db_datareader and public assigned to them. On one of the stored procedures I don't want to give them the right to execute the SP, so I used

```
DENY EXECUTE ON OBJECT::XTR.LoadData TO [AD\Users]
```

when now one of my users connects to the database ALL stored procedures are not visible anymore, the same goes for scalar valued functions (table valued functions they still see).

Did I get a concept totally wrong or why is denying execution on a single object having such effects on all other objects in the same schema ?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but have the users refreshed SSMS?  It is notoriously fickle like that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify any other permissions you gave or denied to the user group AD\Users, I'll assume that they are memebers of db_datareader and public and have no other specific permissions.

To perform my test, I used SQL Server 2008, not R2 and started out with a completely new user group, database, schema and stored procedures.

**As sysadmin**

Created a Windows Group called AD\TEST_USERS in Windows

Created a login from that Windows Group in SQL Server

Created a test database TEST

Added AD\TEST_USERS as a member of public and db_datareader on the TEST database

Created a schema called XTR

Added two stored procedures sp_1 and sp_2 to XTR

**As a member of AD\TEST_USERS**

Opened up SSMS

Opened up the TEST database and expanded stored procedures.  Nothing was visible

**As sysadmin**

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::XTR.sp_1 TO [AD\TEST_USERS]
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::XTR.sp_2 TO [AD\TEST_USERS]
```

**As a member of AD\TEST_USERS**

I refreshed the stored procedures and now see XTR.sp_1 and XTR.sp_2

**As sysadmin**

```
DENY EXECUTE ON OBJECT::XTR.sp_1 TO [AD\TEST_USERS]
```

**As a member of AD\TEST_USERS**

I refresh stored procedures in SSMS and no longer see XTR.sp_1 but I do see XTR.sp2

[image: XTR stored procedures]

Doing the same steps as you on my SQL Server 2008, simply denying EXECUTE on one stored procedure did not make the other stored procedure invisible in the same schema to members of my test group.